# simple inline css in blade not working properly

Tags: html, css, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

so this is the CSS:

```
.header-inner {
    background: url(../images/inner_bg.png), linear-gradient(108deg, #001a30, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) no-repeat;
}
```

i want to inline it to make the background a dynamic value with the blade syntax later on, this is what i did but its not showing the image properly:

```
<div class="header-inner hi-about-us mb-0" style="background: url({{ asset('test-images/inner_bg.png') }}) linear-gradient(108deg, #001a30, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) no-repeat">
```

Comment: Do tell us which one out of the two codes in my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be like this:

```
<div class="header-inner hi-about-us mb-0" style="background: url('{{ asset('test-images/inner_bg.png') }}') linear-gradient(108deg, #001a30, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) no-repeat">
```

The URL should be inside single quotes.

You can also try this:

```
@php
$bgUrl = asset('test-images/inner_bg.png');
@endphp

<div class="header-inner hi-about-us mb-0" style="background: url('{{ $bgUrl }}') linear-gradient(108deg, #001a30, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) no-repeat">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
style="background: url('{{ asset('test-images/inner_bg.png') }}')
```